# I get dependency error when I try installing YUM on CentOS 5.5

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I'm in the process of installing YUM on CentOS 5.5 and following instructionsin this page:
http://wiki.openvz.org/Install_yum

My system is x86_64.

I'm executing the following command:

`rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/rpm-python-4.4.2.3-18.el5.x86_64.rpm`

But then I get the following error:

`error: Failed dependencies:

        popt = 1.10.2.3-18.el5 is needed by rpm-python-4.4.2.3-18.el5.x86_64

        rpm = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 is needed by rpm-python-4.4.2.3-18.el5.x86_64

        rpm-libs = 4.4.2.3-18.el5 is needed by rpm-python-4.4.2.3-18.el5.x86_64`

Any ideas how I can fix this issue?

**Doing 'yum clean' gives methis error**

`There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum.

The error leading to this problem was:  No module named rpm

Please install a package which provides this module,

or verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the current version of Python,

which is: 2.4.3 (#1, Sep  3 2009, 15:37:37)

[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)]`

**Update 2**
Running `rpm -q rpm rpm-libs popt`, it gives me this:

rpm-4.4.2.3-20.el5_5.1
rpm-libs-4.4.2.3-20.el5_5.1
popt-1.10.2.3-20.el5_5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that those dependencies listed are installed (with those versions)?  By providing output of:

```
rpm -q rpm rpm-libs popt
```

I believe you're getting the dependency errors because the versions are not matching up (you have older versions of those RPM's installed).  Try using that same rpm command to update those three RPM's and try again.

Comment: it looks like I've got -20 version, whilst the error message asks for -18 version?

Comment: Try installing from http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.5/updates/x86_64/RPMS instead.  It has the -20 versions of the RPM's.

Answer (score 1):

can try yum clean all and then try to install above rpm

Comment: That didn't work. See above error message.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a CentOS-5.5 machine without yum already installed?

If you follow the instructions here:

http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BrokenVserver

...then you should be able to get a working yum.

Comment: ISP delivers CEntOS without YUM. So there's not much I can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

The sad truth is that, like me, you purchase a broken server. http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BrokenVserver

You will have to either choose to pay extra to get the provider to "unbreak" it for you, or do like I did and eat the setup fees and just find another VPS hosting provider.  Linode comes highly recommended.